# Use large navigation title and fit text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have issue with navigation bar title. First of all I am using large titles with:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Is it possible to have a large title with resizable fonts?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is one property called largeTitleTextAttributes. I think it will solve your problem. 
Write the following code in view controller's viewDidLoad method.

```
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 100)]
```

Comment: I tried this, and I didn't see a change in the displayed text.

Answer (score -1):

You have to resize your title view. Try this

```
    self.title = "Your TiTle Text"
    let tlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
    tlabel.text = self.title
    tlabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    tlabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 30.0)
    tlabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    tlabel.textAlignment = .center;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = tlabel
```

Comment: This doesn't affect the large-title…